# SoapFault: looks like we got no XML document - Magento and laravel

Tags: apache2, php-7.2, ubuntu, laravel-framework, magento1.6.2

I am with a problem in my application Laravel, when i use the SoapClient, for example `my_object_soap->login();` returned this error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught SoapFault exception: [Client] looks like we got
>   no XML

I already tried several solutions that I researched in google and here, but I did not solve my problem.

my code follows:

```
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled",0);
    ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache",0);
    ini_set("error_reporting",-1);
    ini_set("display_errors","On");

    $wsdl_url = "https://example.com/index.php/api/v2_soap/index/?wsdl";
    $apiAuth = new \stdClass();
    $apiAuth->username = trim("myusermagento");
    $apiAuth->apiKey = trim("mykeymagento");

    try{
        $proxy = new SoapClient($wsdl_url,array('cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 'trace' => true));
        $session = $proxy->login($apiAuth);
        $data = $session;
        $status = true;
        $responseStatus = 200;
    } catch(SoapFault $e) {
        $error = $e->getMessage();
        $data = $proxy->__getLastResponse();
        $status = false;
        $responseStatus = 500;
    }        

    return Response::json([
        'success' => $status, 
        'data' => $data,
        'erros'=> $error,
    ],$responseStatus);
```

I have no idea which a problem, when i tested in SoapUI, with this user and key, it's alright, but in my app not.

My magento version app is 1.6.2, and my php is 7.2, I already tried to downgrade to php 5.6 because it could be incompatibility with the magento version and my php but it still did not work.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try following way:

```
<?php
try {
    $user = 'username';
    $password = 'password';
    $proxy = new SoapClient('https://shop.com/api/v2_soap/?wsdl');

    $sessionId = $proxy->login($user, $password);
    var_dump($sessionId);
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: I trying with this code, but i receive this other error: Error cannot find parameter

Comment: but if I transform the parameters into an array object, the previous error will persist